# Unable to get Connection while using Hibernate Spatial

Tags: hibernate, weblogic12c, hibernate-spatial

We are using Weblogic, Hibernate 4.2.7, Hibernate Spatial 4.0 and Oracle as Database.

Upon Performing Save operation some times we are observing Unable to get Connection

Can you suggest any configuration we missed for Spatial ?

```
    Stack Trace :
    Caused by: org.hibernate.spatial.helper.FinderException: Tried retrieving OracleConnection from weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTSConnection_weblogic_jdbc_wrapper_PooledConnection_oracle_jdbc_driver_LogicalConnection using method getConnectionCacheCallbackPrivObj, but received null.
    at org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.oracle.DefaultConnectionFinder.find(DefaultConnectionFinder.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.oracle.DefaultConnectionFinder.find(DefaultConnectionFinder.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.oracle.OracleJDBCTypeFactory.createStruct(OracleJDBCTypeFactory.java:119)
    ... 79 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate Spatial for Oracle DB requires the native oracle connection ([take a look to documentation](http://www.hibernatespatial.org/documentation/03-dialects/05-oracle/) section *The ConnectionFinder Interface*). You must adjust weblogic configuration or implement your own `ConnectionFinder` to provide the Oracle connetion to Hib-Spa.

By example, if you were using use DBCP connection poll you just need set `accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed` property to `true`.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes i have gone through Hibernate Spatial Document, implement my own ConnectionFinder, it worked for me Thanks

Comment: if this is the correct answer, please, mark the check. This way people can identify it easily, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you were using use DBCP connection poll you just need set **accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed** property to **true**`@Bean
    public BasicDataSource dataSource() {

```
    final BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(oracleDriver);
    dataSource.setUrl(oracleUrl);
    dataSource.setUsername(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    dataSource.setInitialSize(initSize);
    dataSource.setMaxIdle(maxIdle);
    dataSource.setMaxActive(maxActive);
    dataSource.setMinIdle(minIdle);
    dataSource.setAccessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed(true);
    return dataSource;
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Spring (Boot) JPA, try

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.spatial.connection_finder=yourpackage.CustomConnectionFinder
```

With the connection finder:

```
public class CustomConnectionFinder implements ConnectionFinder {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomConnectionFinder.class);

    @Override
    public Connection find(Connection connection) {
        try {
            return ((HikariProxyConnection) connection).unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("CustomConnectionFinder: error={}", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```